# Three tables Sql query to Laravel query

Tags: sql, laravel

How can I execute this sql query in laravel?

```
  SELECT * FROM `examination` WHERE `id` in (select `exam_id` from
 `exam_supervision`  where `lecturer_id` in (select `id` from `lecturers` where `id`=1));
```

Laravel seems so confusin. Can anyone please give me the exact laravel query?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use closures in `whereIn` queries.

```
DB::table("examination")->whereIn("id", function ($query) {
        return $query->select("exam_id")
             ->from("exam_supervision")->select("exam_id")
             ->whereIn("lecturer_id", function ($query) {
                     return $query->select("id")
                               ->from("lecturers")
                               ->where("id", 1);
             });
});
```

However the equivalent syntax may be simpler:

```
 DB::table("examination")
     ->join("exam_supervision", "examination.id", "exam_supervision.exam_id")
     ->join("lecturers", "exam_supervision.lecturer_id", "lecturers.id")
     ->where("lecturers.id", 1) 
     ->select(["examination.col1", "examination.col2...]);
```

It also may be quicker to join (but chances are the DBMS has a way of optimising whereIn queries as joins).